# How to hide a terminal icon in toolbar of Eclipse RCP Product?

Tags: terminal, eclipse-rcp, toolbar, rcp

My eclipse rcp project requires the terminal plugins.
 org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui,

After add them on my rcp product, I can open the terminal from Windows->View->Open Terminal.

However I want to hide the terminal icon on the toolbar,I saw in org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui plugin, it defines the location of the Terminal toolbar is located directly in org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar, next to save button.

what should I do? Is there some way to hide it?

Terminal button on toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying postWindowCreate method of ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor class of RCP application.

```
IWorkbenchPage page = this.getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getActivePage();
MenuManager menuBarManager = ((ApplicationWindow)page.getWorkbenchWindow()).getMenuBarManager();
menuBarManager.remove("<ID>"); // pass the id of your terminal toolitem
```